# Thin unable to start after reboot [CentOS 7 + AWS EC2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, thin

I recently acquired an AWS subscription and I'm trying to set up a production environment to host my rails app. I'm using an EC2 instance with CentOS 7 and I'm using mariadb as sql server and thin as my rails server. Everything went fine until I stopped the EC2 instance yesterday. I did not change any configuration and yet I can't get thin to start. I've tried many solutions without success. I'm using a config file to execute thin. If I use the command thin start -e production, it starts successfully, but I've no luck using the config file. The pid and the socket files are not created. I think it is not a problem with my config file, because it worked fine yesterday. Can you give some hints about what the problem may be? Can it be something related to OS configurations, like permissions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After all it was a permissions issue. I wasn't executing the command as root thus it would not run for lack of permissions. Sudo su and it worked like a charm. Thanks anyway!